# Mini_Magick and CarrierWave not resizing image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minimagick

Inside my `avatar_uploader.rb` i have this defined

```
include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
process resize_to_fit: [100, 100]
```

Image uploading works perfectly fine. Its the resizing that i'm having trouble with. No errors, nothing like that. The images just aren't resizing at all. I even tried hard coding the sizing into my `index.html.erb` view like this

```
<%= image_tag(tutor.profile.avatar.url, size: "50, 50") if tutor.profile.avatar? %>
```

But it doesn't work as well. I have read CarrierWave and MiniMagick gem github pages and apparently there's no other additional steps.

Does anyone know if i missed anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution :

---

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.new(avatar_file.path) do |b|
        b.resize '150x150^'
        b.gravity 'Center'
        b.crop '150x150+0+0'
      end
  image.format 'jpg'
  image.write path
```

---

I was using RMagick once, but it took to many resources so I found an alternative and it sounds really great!

Comment: I'll give that a shot and let you know. Any idea whats the difference between resizing using MiniMagick and specifying the size in rails image_tag?